# Duvidas sobre o datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, datagridview, chave-estrangeira

Olá tenho algumas duvidas sobre o datagridview do visual studio, gostaria de saber como posso alterar os valores das colunas que aparecem a foreign key do sql server pelo valor da tabela que é referenciado a chave primaria, e também queria saber como posso somar o total dos valores mostrados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que estou tentando usar, porém ele da erro por que não consigo colocar um String nas colunas por quer foram setadas para int e não consigo alterar isso

```
 public static DataTable fillDataTable(string query)
        {
            using (OdbcConnection conexao = Conexao.CreateConnection())
            {
                OdbcCommand comando = new OdbcCommand(query, conexao);
                conexao.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                try
                {
                    dt.Load(comando.ExecuteReader());


                  for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        String query2 = "SELECT * FROM tbTipoConta WHERE idTipoConta = "+dt.Rows[i][1];
                        List<TipoDeConta> t = CRUD_TipoDeConta.consultaTipoConta(query2);
                        dt.Rows[i][1]= t[0].nomeTipoDeConta;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    throw;
                }

                return dt;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tua pergunta tá muito confusa. Tu queres alterar o valor das colunas `idGasto` e `idTipoConta`, isso?

Comment: eu gostaria  que ao invés de aparecer o numero do id nos campos , aparecesse o nome ao qual esse id é relacionado, vou colocar um código na pergunta, para entender melhor o que eu quero, porém esse código esta dando erro por que estou tentando colocar um String aonde tem um int, e não estou consiguindo mudar o tipo do valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer listar os nomes das tabelas relacionadas ao invés dos seus Id FK e pra isso você vai ter que utilizar inner join do sql para obter o resultado desejado.
Da uma lida em: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp